# Failing to deduce type from lambdas in the initializer list

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, c++11, initializer-list

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace{
//const std::function< void( const int ) > foo[] =
const auto foo[] =
{
  []( const int v ){ std::cout<<v<<std::endl; },
  []( const int v ){ std::cout<<v/2<<std::endl; },
  []( const int v ){ std::cout<<v/3<<std::endl; },
};

}

int main()
{
  foo[1](5);
}
```

The above example fails to compile (using g++ 4.6.1) with next error message:

```
error: unable to deduce 'const std::initializer_list<const auto> []' from '{{}, {}, {}}'
```

The commented line works fine (without specifying the function type).

Is this a quirk of g++? Or is there anything in the standard that tells the above should not compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this. Each lambda has an unique, unrelated type. If you want a collection of lambdas, you have to erase the type with `std::function`:

```
std::function<void(int)> foo[] = {
    [](int) { ... },
    [](int) { ... },
    ...
};
```

Even in

```
auto f1 = []{};
auto f2 = []{};
```

the two types are different.

Comment: `[expr.prim.lambda]/3` tells exactly that. Not sure how I failed to see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others say about the lambdas having unique types, you are not allowed to use `auto` as the specifier in an array variable declaration. Even the following is ill-formed

```
auto x[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // 'auto' disallowed
```

Comment: I understand it wouldn't be able to deduce from `{1, 2.0, 4u}`, but why from all ints?